# Null value for related object in ef core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

There are Tasks and TaskGroups. A Task may be assigned to one group. But this is not necessary.
My ef models are looking like that:

```
public TaskMSSQLModel
{
   [Key]
   public int TaskId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int? TaskGroupId {get;set;}
   public TaskGroupMSSQLModel TaskGroup {get;set;}
}

public TaskGroupMSSQLModel
{
   [Key]
   public int TaskGroupId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I also have the following Business Models

```
public TaskModel
{
   [Key]
   public int TaskId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public TaskGroupModel TaskGroup {get;set;}
}

public TaskGroupModel
{
   [Key]
   public int TaskGroupId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want the TaskGroup in my business model to be null, when there a Task is not assigned to a TaskGroup.
I tried the following, but it is not working and ef core says, that I have to rewrite my query.

```
context.Task.Select(x => new TaskModel
            {
                TaskId = x.TaskId,
                Name = x.Name,
                TaskGroup = x.TaskGroupId.HasValue ? new TaskGroupModel
                {
                    TaskGroupId = x.TaskGroup.TaskGroupId,
                    Name = x.TaskGroup.Name
                } : null
             }
```

I can do it like this:

```
context.Task.Select(x => new TaskModel
            {
                TaskId = x.TaskId,
                Name = x.Name,
                TaskGroup = new TaskGroupModel
                {
                    TaskGroupId = x.TaskGroup.TaskGroupId,
                    Name = x.TaskGroup.Name
                }
             }
```

but then I have an empty TaskGroup-Object, what I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that EF Core doesn't know how to translate the `.HasValue` inside the select. You could first give this a try:

```
context.Task
   .Select(x => new TaskModel
   {
      TaskId = x.TaskId,
      Name = x.Name,
      TaskGroup = 
         x.TaskGroupId != null
            ? new TaskGroupModel
               {
                  TaskGroupId = x.TaskGroup.TaskGroupId,
                  Name = x.TaskGroup.Name
               } 
            : null
   });
```

If that doesn't work, then I think you will have to materialise your query before mapping it to your business model.

```
context.Task
   .ToList() // Load the TaskModelMSSQLModels into memory first
   .Select(x => new TaskModel
   {
      TaskId = x.TaskId,
      Name = x.Name,
      TaskGroup = 
         x.TaskGroupId.HasValue 
            ? new TaskGroupModel
               {
                  TaskGroupId = x.TaskGroup.TaskGroupId,
                  Name = x.TaskGroup.Name
               } 
            : null
   });
```

On a side note, you might want to look into [Automapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/) for handling the mapping between `Dto <-> Business Model <-> Database Model`